# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: python, selenium

Currently working to use Python to login with Twitter.

Twitter's login page is [here](https://twitter.com/login). The source code where the Username and Password input fields are:

```
<div class="LoginForm-input LoginForm-username">
<input
  type="text"
  class="text-input email-input js-signin-email"
  name="session[username_or_email]"
  autocomplete="username"
  placeholder="Phone, email or username"
/>
</div>

<div class="LoginForm-input LoginForm-password">
<input type="password" class="text-input" name="session[password]" 
placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
</div>
```

So when I write my code in Python utilizing the Selenium module:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(username)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("session[password]")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(password)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(delay)
```

The error that is returned:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element 
>       is not currently visible and so may not be
>       interacted with

Any help? Thanks! I have read of the responses of other similar questions, but have not helped much.

**Edit:**

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 154, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 143, in main
    twitterBruteforce(username, wordlist, delay)
  File "src/twitterLib.py", line 27, in twitterBruteforce
    elem.clear()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 88, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 457, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpurkUhr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpurkUhr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpurkUhr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpurkUhr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpurkUhr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Comment: which exact element is not visible? show full exception log

Comment: updated my post. thanks :)

Comment: Not clear.. could you tell us in which line this exception occurred?? Is this exception occurred at `elem.clear()` line?? But you are using same variable for both element why??

Comment: 'elem = driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")'

Comment: But this line only finding the element.. this exception can be occurred during interaction to the element like using as `.clear()` or `send_keys()`..

Comment: And are you sure your locator locats the correct element??

Comment: So would it be occurring here: elem.send_keys(username) ? Username is a variable that I do specify in my code but excluded here

Comment: Yes it would be at `elem.send_keys(username)` or `elem.clear()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible before interaction to the element as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

user = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "session[username_or_email]")))
user.clear()
user.send_keys(username)

pass = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "session[password]")))
pass.clear()
pass.send_keys(password)
```

**Note** :- instead of `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` try using `click()` to the login button element as `login_button_element.click()` or try using `submit()` to the form element as `form_element.submit()` after locating these elements.